Locating One of Martial's Epigrams
Having found a snippet of one of Martial's Epigrams:

"You dine so well, it's clear that you are rich, yet you don't pay your debts, which is a bitch,".

Amused and intrigued I tried to locate the rest and the original Latin. Sadly, without the number or the title, this was unsuccessful.
Is there a way to locate the original?
During this frustration I read some of Martial's work. Quick to criticise and heap scorn on others, was this chappie! It may be that he was nursing sins of his own: "we most hate in others what we see in ourselves", comes to mind. Is there any evidence for this?
He lauded Emperor Domitian; then, after his death, Martial pointed the late Emperor's failings.
When Martial retired to Hispania, was that to escape those whom he had upset?

Can you cite where you got that translation?

@cmw: I was looking for a different Martial translation and a chatbot gave an answer, along with the above example. I don't trust these translations; they are often wrong! When I asked for the original Latin, it declined for "copyright" reasons. As if Latin literature can be subject to copyright. People fear AI; but, for the present, at least, it's hopelessly inadequate. (When I point out wrong answers it apologises and then repeats the same wrong answer. I have to teach it!!)

If a chatbot gave it to you, I'm sure it's fake.

@cmw: Which accounts for the fact that it could not be found. Therefore, why do people fear AI? Have you experimented with this? Your findings?

tony: I answered instead of commenting further, but changing the title and adding in the information about the AI might attract more attention to this question.

Also, the questions of Martial's attitudes might be better off in a question of its own!

You indicate that this "translation" comes from Martial via AI, but here's the note of caution with using AI to gather facts. I don't believe there is such a couplet in Martial.
Chat-GPT and similar LLMs are designed to imitate how we write, but they cannot, as of yet, discern truth from falsehoods or intelligently work through complex problems. They also are prone to "hallucinations", fabrications of data. ChatGPT has regularly given me fake information, fake citations, wrong sources, made-up books. It's not fact-driven, but speech-driven. It's aim is to emulate the way humans write, regardless of the facts.
Regarding the poem, the rhyming couplets probably reflects the source material, i.e. heavy on English sources, in the poetry of which rhyming couplets are ubiquitous. While talented translators can convey the meaning of Latin poetry and still rhyme, it's rare among modern translations (note the phrasing: that's a bitch), and should immediately raise suspicions.
While the couplet isn't authentic Martial, it does summarize many of the themes found in Martial, who often casts himself in the role of the parasite-guest. "Eat[ing] well" is a common phrase throughout Martial (4.68, 7.78, 9.19, 10.31) as well as Latin literature as a whole (found in Lucilius, Catullus, Horace, and Juvenal, three satirists and an epigrammatist ranging from the 2nd century BCE to the 2nd century CE!), and both the manners of rude guests and stingy hosts are frequently attacked, such as in Mart. 1.20:

Dic mihi, quis furor est? turba spectante vocata
    Solus boletos, Caeciliane, voras.
Quid dignum tanto tibi ventre gulaque precabor?
    Boletum qualem Claudius edit, edas.
Tell me, what madness is this? While a whole crowd of invited guests is looking on, you alone, Caecilianus, devour the truffles. What shall I imprecate on you worthy of so large a stomach and throat? That you may eat a truffle such as Claudius ate. [Trans. Bohn]

Despite all this, you do see a couplet in Martial (10.54) that is similar to the one a chatbot spit out at you, though it's not a perfect match:

Mensas, Ole, bonas ponis, sed ponis opertas.
    Ridiculum est: possum sic ego habere bonas.
You put fine dishes on your table, Olus, but you always put them on covered. This is ridiculous; in the same way I could put fine dishes on my [own] table. [Trans. Bohn]

This is the same Olus that earlier (3.48) clearly had to go into debt to finance a summer retreat:

Pauperis extruxit cellam, sed vendidit Olus
    Praedia: nunc cellam pauperis Olus habet.
Olus built a poor man's cot, and sold his farms. Olus now inhabits the poor man's cot. [Trans. Bohn]

Martial spells out the debt more clearly in 7.10:

Pro togula debes: hoc ad te pertinet, Ole.
Quadrantem nemo iam tibi credit: et hoc.
Uxor moecha tibi est: hoc ad te pertinet, Ole.
Poscit iam dotem filia grandis: et hoc.
Dicere quindecies poteram, quod pertinet ad te:
Sed quid agas, ad me pertinet, Ole, nihil.
You are in debt for your paltry toga; that, Olus, concerns you. No one will any longer give you a farthing's credit; that, Olus, concerns you. Your wife plays the adulteress; that, Olus, concerns you. Your daughter is grown up, and demands a dowry; that, Olus, concerns you. I could mention some fifteen other things that concern you; but your affairs, Olus, concern me not at all.

We have some shared elements here:

The main animosity in 10.54 revolves around dining;
Olus gives the appearance of wealth, but hides his true poverty (appearing stingy in 10.54, but readers, should they remember 3.48, will know of his real poverty);
That poverty is due to debt in 3.48;


(so much so that even a toga sets him back in 7.10)



It's not an exact match, and you need two of Martial's poems to get close to the English, but the themes are there. You could even see the English couplet as a modern American take on Martial's themes. With 15 books of epigrams, you might find another couplet (or several lines) that looks similar to what the AI gave you, but I think there's a real reason the AI didn't give you a citation: it doesn't exist.

Thank you for this comprehensive answer. Do you have strong feelings about AI and/or a special interest in Martial? I enjoyed the reading and some "new" Latin, "hoc ad te pertinet" = "this concerns you"; lit. "this is relevant to you", I think. If the affairs of Olus did not concern Martial at all, why did he write the epigram?

@tony At least what Martial says to the emperor is that he's just writing poetry for poetry's sake. See the introduction to book 1 and epigram iv to Domitian.
